# footer won't actually stick to bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a page there:

I'm a newbie and followed a tutorial there: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

The footer is at the bottom but the height of the page seems to be bigger than it should be and there is a scrolling bar on my browser, anybody can tell me why ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra height seems to be coming from the padding-top on #footer-container, the border on #footer, and most significantly the margin on #masthead-container (changing this to padding on #content-container seems to fix it).

Getting rid of all of those, eliminates the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

The `<footer>` has a `padding-top` which should be counted in the box model. So the actual margin bottom of wrapper should count both the height and padding of the footer. Look into the html box model for more details! It'll surely be fun :) And also, use Chrome developer tools or Firefox firebug to speed up your learning process

Answer (score 0):

Your link doesn't open. But maybe you can do something like

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.footer {
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done some changes in your the style you wrote. just replace your code that is written for #footer.

```
 #footer {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #D2CECE;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    box-shadow: 4px 5px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    clear: both;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 193px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 960px;
 }
```

I have set the left margin as 193px which you need adjust.
you should add a main container div to contain all mark up in the .
like

```
   <body>
       <div id="main">
           <!-- all the markup (HTML code) -->
       </div>
  </body>
```

so by applying style to "#main" you can make all the contain center align and no need to give left or right margin to make it center.